# Encrypting sensitive application data in Java

Tags: java, encryption, file

I'm currently assessing a project where highly sensitive personal information is handled thus it needs to be encrypted. We are talking like several 100 megabytes of multimedia files, like MP3 or something else. The application will most certainly be implemented in Java with JavaFX as GUI/Frontend. Now I am searching for a feasible solution to protect that data from unintentional/intentional misuse. The data needs to be encrypted somehow. The user needs to provide login credentials before using the software, so using the password to unlock a key used for symmetric crypto would be possible. The users of the application will be non professional thus things like TrueCrypt or similar solutions won't do the trick. Although some kind of transparent solution would be best. So is there any (semi-) standard solution for this problem?

Thanks for the help

Greetings,

Andreas

Comment: Did you try taking a look at JCE(Java Cryptography Extension)? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html

Comment: Actually this was a good hint but I was more searching for some kind of ready to use library that provides everything for me. But the Cipher{Input,Output}Stream classes are looking good and it should be a problem to create some kind of wrapper around them for providing transparent encryption for certain files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method encrypts a given byte array, where keyC is the encryption key.
initalVector is the initial vector used for the encryption. 
This vector is typically used for AES encryption in counter (CTR) mode, but is not necessary for other modes. It's an array of a certain 16 bytes, used for encrypting and decrypting.

```
private byte[] encryptAES128(byte[] input, byte[] initialVector) {
    SecretKey aeskey = new SecretKeySpec(keyC, 0, 16, "AES");
    AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NOPADDING");
    getAesCTRCipher().init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskey, paramSpec);
    return getAesCTRCipher().doFinal(input);
}
```

This method returns a new byte array, being the encrypted input array.
It always works in blocks of 16 bytes.
For larger files, you need run a for loop over the bytes and concatenate the result :)

Good luck!

Edit:
After encrypting a block of 16 bytes, you need to increment the initial vector, that is if the encryption runs in Counter mode :)

Comment: Thats not exactly answering the question as i dont want to have anything to do with the internals of the crypto where things can go wrong, i.e. forgetting to increment the IV. In my opinion these things are prone to error

Comment: There's other encryption modes than CTR, who don't require a IV. Imo this is a very handy solution

Answer (score -3):

Use a public-key encryption algorithm, such as RSA. strong, almost uncrackable and easy to use and understand. there's probably even a method or even a class for RSA or similar encryptions in Java.

Comment: Not really an answer, and not really correct either as far as it goes.

Comment: The theory of doing so is quite clear to me as a computer science major. But doing encryption by oneself is in most cases a really bad idea.